# Python calling OpenSSL function segfaults

Tags: python-3.x, openssl

I have a .p8 file download from Apple's iOS developer portal for PushNotifications.

I am trying to load the P8 file with the following code in Python:

```
from ctypes import *
OpenSSL = cdll.LoadLibrary("/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib")


def loadPrivateKey(path):
    bio = OpenSSL.BIO_new_file(path.encode("utf-8"), "rb".encode("utf-8"))
    #pKey = OpenSSL.PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio, None, None, None)
    OpenSSL.BIO_free(bio)

def main():
    loadPrivateKey("/users/Brandon/Desktop/APNsAuthKey.p8")

main()
```

However, it seg faults on the line: `OpenSSL.BIO_free(bio)`. I have checked if bio has a value other than 0 (it does).

If I do the same thing in C, it works:

```
struct EVP_PKEY* loadPrivateKey(const char* path)
{
    struct BIO* bio = BIO_new_file(path, "rb");
    struct EVP_PKEY* pKey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free(bio);
    return pKey;
}

int main()
{
    struct EVP_PKEY* pKey = loadPrivateKey("/users/Brandon/Desktop/APNsAuthKey.p8");
    EVP_PKEY_free(pKey);
}
```

I have verified in C that the code works and I have used it to sign data. I have been unable to do the same in Python3 because freeing the BIO segfaults with code 11.

I have tried `pyOpenssl`, and it also segfaults when I try to read the key with `loadprivatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, key)` where key is the contents of the P8 file.

Any ideas why it would segfault?

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL are you supplying, and which version of OpenSSL does Python expect? OpenSSL 1.0.2 and OpenSSL 1.1.0 are *not* binary compatible.

Comment: @jww; I solved it. After trying for hours.. It turns out you need to specify the types and the types must be a perfect match. Otherwise it fails. For some odd reason `pyOpenSSL` segfaults even though it is using `ffi`. I ended up using the solution I posted since none of the third party libraries work atm and I can't find any other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else is having the same issues.. You MUST specify the `argtypes` and `restype`. To do that, you need to assign the function pointer to a temporary variable, specify the types and then call it using the temporary.

Example:

```
from ctypes import *
OpenSSL = cdll.LoadLibrary("/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib")


def BIO_new_file(path):
    BIO_new_file_func = OpenSSL.BIO_new_file
    BIO_new_file_func.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p]
    BIO_new_file_func.restype = c_void_p
    return BIO_new_file_func(path.encode("utf-8"), "rb".encode("utf-8"))

def BIO_free(bio):
    BIO_free_func = OpenSSL.BIO_free
    BIO_free_func.argtypes = [c_void_p]
    BIO_free_func.restype = None
    return BIO_free_func(bio)


def loadPrivateKey(path):
    bio = BIO_new_file(path)
    #pKey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio, None, None, None)
    BIO_free(bio)
    #return pKey

def main():
    loadPrivateKey("/users/Brandon/Desktop/APNsAuthKey.p8")

main()
```

I was under the impression that I just had to call the functions with the right arguments and it'd work but I was wrong. You have to specify the types! Otherwise use `FFI` and make your life easier.